# Unable to find my camera's RTSP url while using opencv-python

Tags: python, rtsp, opencv

I am using MatrixIPCamera model: SATATYA CIDR20FL36CWS camera from where I want to take video feed into my python code.

I am using:

```
import cv2
import os
camera = "rtsp://<username>:<password>@<Ip address>:<Port>/Streaming/Channels/2/" 
video = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
```

But every time I am getting:

```
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-l1r0y34w/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (160) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-req-build-l1r0y34w/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): rtsp://<username>:<password>@<Ip address>:<Port>/Streaming/Channels/2/ in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

Results of print(cv.getBuildInformation())

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.3 =====================================
  Version control:               4.5.3-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-07-09T11:59:03Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.8.0-1036-azure x86_64
    CMake:                       3.20.5
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/c++  (ver 9.3.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /lib64/libpng.so /lib64/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.0-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.5.13)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.109.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.61.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.60.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.8.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /tmp/pip-req-build-l1r0y34w/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /tmp/pip-req-build-l1r0y34w/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    VA:                          NO
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /tmp/pip-req-build-l1r0y34w/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python (ver 3.7.9)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.7m.a (ver 3.7.9)
    numpy:                       /tmp/pip-build-env-r4l7zyhq/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.14.5)
    install path:                python

  Python (for build):            /bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /tmp/pip-req-build-l1r0y34w/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looks like GStreamer is missing.
...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you access that same url with VLC video player?

Comment: `print(cv.getBuildInformation())` and add to your post. you are likely missing gstreamer.

Comment: @Micka No, I cannot access that same url with VLC

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz added. Please check edit.

Comment: You replaced the <contens> with the actual information, right?

Comment: ok so you need gstreamer because I don't think that ffmpeg can handle rtsp (gstreamer does).

Comment: @Micka Yes I did

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz No I can access Hikvison cameras using RTSP.

Comment: well, CAP_IMAGES is the last backend that is ever tried, which means no higher priority backend (not even ffmpeg) claimed to be responsible for handling your rtsp URL